# setting interval distance for notifications in requestLocationUpdate in android

Tags: android, geolocation, power-management

`requestLocationUpdate` allows one to set the interval distance for notifications.

Does anyone know how this works?

I mean, does the manager location simply screen out unwanted changes?

Or does it use an android utility to detect if the device has moved, and by doing so using less battery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

given the documentation I think it's fair to assume the interval distance just screens out certain changes.  It specifically mentions saving battery power w/ the time interval, but not with the minDistance.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long

"The frequency of notification may be controlled using the minTime and minDistance parameters. If minTime is greater than 0, the LocationManager could potentially rest for minTime milliseconds between location updates to conserve power. If minDistance is greater than 0, a location will only be broadcasted if the device moves by minDistance meters. To obtain notifications as frequently as possible, set both parameters to 0."